# Handle OAM Timeouts in Angular 6 with Route-Resolvers

Tags: typescript, angular6, rxjs6, angular-http-interceptors, oracle-access-manager

I have an Angular 6 application which uses OAM authentication cookie to communicate with back-end web services. OAM sessions are set to expire after X minutes or when the same user has logged in from another device. I want to handle this and display a popup window to the users so that they can click and navigate them to the Login page. I have created an HttpInterceptor and call a service to display the popup window.

When I deploy the application (build it using `ng build` and production mode configurations) it works fine whenever the session expires and the next user action is to navigate to a path which **does not have a route resolver** defined in the routing module, i.e. services are called within the component after initialization. Whenever I try to navigate to a path which needs a resolver to be called first nothing happens. I tried adding console logs and redeployed several times to see what could be wrong but the resolver as well as the interceptor are not even called. I just get the following errors in the Console tab and no navigation takes place:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <       at https://login...?bmctx=920634F2F55...e9b2.js`

`Error: Loading chunk 21 failed...`

From what I understand, the 1st error is because it's trying to parse the response of the request (which is from OAM's automatic redirection to the login page) and the `<` character is the beginning of `<!DOCTYPE html>`. By the way, this is the same response which returns error code 200 and which I check in my interceptor in order to display the pop-up window.

**The weird thing is that this does not happen when I run the application in debug mode (using `ng serve` command). The interceptor is invoked correctly and in all cases! Could it be something related to my build configurations or am I missing something related to OAM timeout handling?**

See below some sections of my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class ResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private alertMessageService: AlertMessagesService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError((error: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => {

      if ((error.status === 200 || error.status === 0) && error.url.indexOf('login.') !== -1) {
        this.alertMessageService.displayLogoutConfirmation();
        return of(error);
      }

      throw error;
    }));
  }
}
```

Deployment build configurations in angular.json:

```
"configurations": {
    "dev1": {
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/./environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/./environments/environment.prodpro.ts"
        }
      ]
    },
```